# Screen goes into power saving mode on boot up

Tags: power-management, screen

I have an annoying problem in that when I turn my computer on my monitor (an LG Flatron) immediately goes into power saving mode and I can see nothing but a black screen, apart from occasional flashes as the boot up process continues. This necessitates me having to use the reset button numerous times until I "get lucky" and actually manage to see the screen and log in as normal. Sometimes this process can take 15 to 20 minutes. Once logged in with a visible screen, however, there is no problem. I can even restart the system without problems. The problem only occurs when the computer is turned on for the first time, e.g. in the morning after having been switched off all night. Can anyone suggest what the problem might be?

Comment: Did you take a look at [Monitor goes into power saving mode after grub selection?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55961/monitor-goes-into-power-saving-mode-after-grub-selection)

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old problem which has now been solved. It was a hardware problem that has been fixed.