# Monitor goes into power saving mode after grub selection

Tags: 11.04, server

I installed Ubuntu Server. It loads just fine to the grub selection screen but after making a selection, for some reason the monitor just goes into power saving mode and never wakes back up. I have to restart. The monitor cables are not loose or anything. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: what happens if you start in failsafe or whatever mode?

Comment: Have you tried hitting crtl+alt+backspace when it goes to sleep? Also, could you tag this with the version you are using?

Comment: @user606723 - The same thing happens. Monitor just goes into power saving mode.

Comment: @Bryan Agee - I tried it, but it didn't do anything. I just tagged the version which is 11.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amye, press 'e' to edit the grub command line (the one that starts with 'linux') and add the word 'nomodeset' to the end of the line. If that doesn't work, also remove 'quiet' from the word list. That should at least give you some extra clues as to when it is getting stuck.

If that works, you may want to add this line to /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_EXTRA="nomodeset"
```

And then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

To make it permanent.

Comment: Thanks SpamapS! I added nomodeset and now its working perfectly :)

Comment: Note, as a follow up, that you may want to file a bug in grub so that your hardware will be blacklisted in future releases (or so that somebody can fix it :)