# After selecting Grub entry, screen switches to power save

Tags: boot, grub2, luks

After I select an entry (Ubuntu) from the Grub menu, the screen goes to power save mode.

I could eventually get the screen asking me for the HDD encryption password by pressing Alt-F1 and then Alt-F7 (Alt-F7 alone did not work). Then I could enter my password and the boot process continued normally.

This behaviour (screen switching to power save) has occured since the upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10.

I have some non-standard disk layout (RAID, LVM, LUKS encrpytion), maybe it is related to that. I also had the ["disfilter writes are not supported" problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468466/why-this-occurs-error-diskfilter-writes-are-not-supported), but could solve it with `quick_boot="0"`.

UPDATE:

I tried appending `nomodeset` [as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55961/monitor-goes-into-power-saving-mode-after-grub-selection) (i.e., I pressed "e" and then added it to the line which starts with `linux`). Now the monitor did not switch to power save and I immediately got the password screen for unlocking the encrypted harddisk. But when I typed, no dots showed up, and nothing happened when I pressed enter. After switching screens, on Alt-F7 I saw the password as raw text (and nothing else). So this did not help at all, I would rather say that it's worse than before ...